# Dependency analyzer/optimizer for package.json and bower.json

Tags: javascript

Is there any project that is capable of analyzing a web app's `package.json` and `bower.json` files, in order to provide

- recommendations,
- alternatives,
- best practice tips,
- pros/cons, and
- report?

It's quite cumbersome to keep up with the changing landscape of frameworks and projects; what's hot and what's not, abandoned/dead projects and what are considered, by the community at large to be best practices. A software solution that provides these recommendations would be ideal.

Playing the software equivalent of "keeping up with the Joneses," isn't a game I'm remotely interested in playing; and choosing a technology because it's being used by a bunch of sheep doesn't seem like a prudent/efficient approach to choosing on frameworks/modules/dependencies. It'd be nice to run said software against an already existing application and analyze based on the vectors listed above in the most objective manner possible.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there are tools that can recommend alternatives and *best practice tips* for a few reasons:

- Every package published on npm doesn't have an alternative.
- Every package would have to have a way index some alternatives (which is kind of working against yourself, you're advertising your competition), or the package would have to keep a huge listing of tons of alternatives.
- Best practice tips are sometimes opinion-based.
- You can find best practices for packages in their own documentation (I would hope they document it with its best usage).

There are tools, however, that can analyze your `package.json` for various different reasons, and then do things with what it finds:

For instance:

- [npm-check](https://github.com/dylang/npm-check): Check for outdated, incorrect, and unused dependencies.
- [npm-check-updates](https://github.com/tjunnone/npm-check-updates): Find newer versions of dependencies than what your package.json or bower.json allows
- [license-checker](https://github.com/davglass/license-checker): Check license info for a package and it's dependencies.
- [updatr](https://github.com/peerigon/updtr): Update outdated npm modules with zero pain™
- [ur](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ur): Analyze a node project for packages that are required but not included in the package.json, or in package.json but not required.
- [`npm view`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view): Get a package's information.
- [package-info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/package-info): Get the information of a npm package
- [bower-installer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bower-installer): Tool for installing bower dependencies that won't include entire repos
- [ember-cli](http://ember-cli.com/): The command line interface for ambitious web applications.

And probably many many more.

Comment: man (or woman). this is great! thanks a ton. this answer should suffice.